# NotImplementedException from .NET's CustomLineCap constructor

Tags: .net, gdi+, system.drawing, notimplementedexception

I want to draw a custom line cap - a equilateral triangle with the radius r. Apparently I can't:

```
  Dim triangleSide As Single = CSng(3 * r / Math.Sqrt(3))
  Dim triangleHeight As Single = CSng(3 * r / 2)
  path = New GraphicsPath()
  Dim points() As PointF = New PointF() { _ 
      New PointF(-triangleSide / 2, 0), _ 
      New PointF(triangleSide / 2, 0), _
      New PointF(0, triangleHeight) }
  path.AddLines(points)

  ' Not Implemented Exception, Was is Das? '
  _HlpCap = New CustomLineCap(path, Nothing)
```

Do I something wrong or it's just a framework bug?

EDIT:

After Mark Cidade remark, I tried using `(Nothing, path)` and it helped, but I need to fill in the triangle, not only to stroke it out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception comes from the GDI+ library returning a `NotImplemented` status from its `GdipCreateCustomLineCap()` function. Try passing a stroke path instead of `Nothing`:

```
  Dim path2 As GraphicsPath = New GraphicsPath()
  path2.AddLines(points);
  _HlpCap = New CustomLineCap(path, path2)
```

Comment: The `fillPath` and `strokePath` parameters cannot be used at the same time. One parameter must be passed a null value. If neither parameter is passed a null value, `fillPath` will be ignored. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the path cannot cross the x-axis. I used this code to create an arrow cap:

```
  GraphicsPath capPath = new GraphicsPath();
  float arrowSize = 2.0f;
  capPath.AddLines(new PointF[] {
    new PointF(arrowSize, -(float)Math.Sqrt(3.0) * arrowSize),
    new PointF(0.0f, -0.01f),
    new PointF(-arrowSize, -(float)Math.Sqrt(3.0) * arrowSize)
  });

  CustomLineCap arrowCap = new CustomLineCap(capPath, null, LineCap.NoAnchor, (float)Math.Sqrt(3.0) * arrowSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Bad

Here's an example of a `GraphicsPath` that tries to draw an arrow head beyond the end of the line and causes a `System.NotImplementedException`.

```
GraphicsPath capPath = new GraphicsPath();
capPath.AddLine(0, 8, -5, 0);
capPath.AddLine(-5, 0, 5, 0);
arrowPen.CustomEndCap = new CustomLineCap(capPath, null); // System.NotImplementedException
```

This fails because the path must intercept the negative Y-axis.  But the path above only passes through the origin and doesn't actually hit the negative Y-axis.

The [remarks in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.customlinecap.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8) are crucially important:

> The `fillPath` and `strokePath` parameters cannot be used at the same time. One parameter must be passed a null value. If neither parameter is passed a null value, `fillPath` will be ignored. If `strokePath` is `null`, `fillPath` should intercept the negative y-axis.

This is one of those cases where the wording is poor.  The docs say "*should* intercept" but I think it's the case that it "*must* intercept" or else you're going to get a `System.NotImplementedException`.  This intercept issue applies only to a `fillPath`, and not a `strokePath`.  (The documentation could probably use some pictures too.)

### Good

Here's an example of a `GraphicsPath` that draws an arrow head at the end of the line and works correctly.  And it's likely the kind of arrow head that most people want to draw anyway.

[image]

```
GraphicsPath capPath = new GraphicsPath();
capPath.AddLine(0, 0, -5, -8);
capPath.AddLine(-5, -8, 5, -8);
arrowPen.CustomEndCap = new CustomLineCap(capPath, null); // OK
```

### Fixing Your Example

A fix is to just subtract the `triangleHeight` from y.  This places the tip of the arrow at 0,0 (which are the coordinates of the end of the line) which is likely what you intended anyway, and puts the base of the triangle at `-triangleHeight`.

```
float radius = 5.0f;
float triangleSide = 3.0f * radius / (float)Math.Sqrt(3.0f);
float triangleHeight = 3.0f * radius / 2.0f;
GraphicsPath capPath = new GraphicsPath();
capPath.AddLines(new PointF[] {
    new PointF(-triangleSide / 2.0f, -triangleHeight),
    new PointF(triangleSide / 2.0f, -triangleHeight),
    new PointF(0, 0) }
);
arrowPen.CustomEndCap = new CustomLineCap(capPath, null);
```

#### The exact fix for you (in Visual Basic):

```
  Dim points() As PointF = New PointF() { _ 
      New PointF(-triangleSide / 2, -triangleHeight), _ 
      New PointF(triangleSide / 2, -triangleHeight), _
      New PointF(0, 0) }
  path.AddLines(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had made the lenght of the cap's segments dependant on the conteiner's width. My program always stopped with an exception whenever I shrinked the form past a certain limit.
Then I discovered that the exception was thrown when any segment's length reached 1.
So, make sure that all the segments in your cap path have a length greater than 1.